# Globbing in Windows to process images - how do bash loops look in DOS?

Tags: convert, windows, digital-image-processing, osx, command-line

I'm doing some batch image processing with imagemagick on OSX using this line:

```
for file in $(cat all.txt); do convert -crop 50X50@ +repage +adjoin "$file" "$file"_tile_50x50@_%d.jpeg; done
```

It takes a filelist as an input, chops each file into 50x50 pixel tiles, and labels the output with the original filename and an index number (%d). The quantity of imagery is about 400+ source images, and hence 1,000,000 output images.

I have to move the processing to a Windows 10 box. Can someone help me translate the above loop across, or suggest a better way to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, answering my own question again; hoping someone else finds it useful! Using Windows Powershell, the below. Place the source images (`jpeg` image files in my example) in directory `foo`, the create the `outputdir` directory. Then execute this command:

```
dir -recurse -include *.jpeg | %{convert $._FullName -crop 50x50@ +repage +adjoin “C:\foo\bar\outputdir\$($_.Name)”}
```

Loads of thanks to the contributors on [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784057/run-a-simple-command-using-powershell-recursively-on-a-directory) for giving the right structure and keywords for me to solve the problem.